# Google Mobile Vision with Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an App using Xamarin Forms , the App required a barcode scanning facility so I used Zxing because it is free, it works but with limitation with small barcodes.  I came cross Google Mobile Vision and found that it support both Android and iOS from this link [Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction)

I couldn't find out how to implement this using Xamarin Forms.

Note: I'm not that expert with Xamarin.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Try  [Rb.Forms.Barcode](https://github.com/rebuy-de/rb-forms-barcode).

Comment: Hey, I implemented Google Mobile Vision on android for OCR scanning. Works fine but you have to do it in your android project (Add Google Mobile Vision NuGet). Looking for a IOS implementation.